# Post building event C++ VS 2012

Tags: c++, compilation

Hello I have one issue with my compilation

I have MSB3073 error 1

The command which was in VS2008 project is
    setlocal

```
set SDK_USAGE=1
if $(Configuration) == Debug_DLLOnly_ANSI (set SDK_USAGE=0)
if $(Configuration) == Debug_DLLOnly_UNICODE (set SDK_USAGE=0)
if $(Configuration) == Release_DLLOnly_ANSI (set SDK_USAGE=0)
if $(Configuration) == Release_DLLOnly_UNICODE (set SDK_USAGE=0)
if $(Configuration) == Debug_LIBOnly_ANSI (set SDK_USAGE=2)
if $(Configuration) == Debug_LIBOnly_UNICODE (set SDK_USAGE=2)
if $(Configuration) == Release_LIBOnly_ANSI (set SDK_USAGE=2)
if $(Configuration) == Release_LIBOnly_UNICODE (set SDK_USAGE=2)


set IS_64BIT=0
if $(Platform) == x64 (set IS_64BIT=1)

if exist FileCopy.bat (call FileCopy.bat %25SDK_USAGE%25 %25IS_64BIT%25 "$(TargetDir)")
```

I tried follow code after find it http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8e379465-e07b-415d-af8a-5c9e7064a95c/error-msb3073-command-exited-with-code-1-while-building-the-project?forum=tfsbuild

```
setlocal

set SDK_USAGE=1
if $(Configuration) == Debug_DLLOnly_ANSI (set SDK_USAGE=0)
if $(Configuration) == Debug_DLLOnly_UNICODE (set SDK_USAGE=0)
if $(Configuration) == Release_DLLOnly_ANSI (set SDK_USAGE=0)
if $(Configuration) == Release_DLLOnly_UNICODE (set SDK_USAGE=0)
if $(Configuration) == Debug_LIBOnly_ANSI (set SDK_USAGE=2)
if $(Configuration) == Debug_LIBOnly_UNICODE (set SDK_USAGE=2)
if $(Configuration) == Release_LIBOnly_ANSI (set SDK_USAGE=2)
if $(Configuration) == Release_LIBOnly_UNICODE (set SDK_USAGE=2)


set IS_64BIT=0
if $(Platform) == x64 (set IS_64BIT=1)

if exist FileCopy.bat (call FileCopy.bat %25SDK_USAGE%25 %25IS_64BIT%25 '$(TargetDir)')
```

But unsuccessful do you have some idea for me please?

Best Regards.

Edit : I solve my problem in delete if exist FileCopy.bat (call FileCopy.bat %25SDK_USAGE%25 %25IS_64BIT%25 '$(TargetDir)')